# Creating a Gesture Recognizer from code

Tags: c#, ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, selector

I am trying to create a gesture recognizer from code, however I can't get it to work, I get a `unrecognised selector sent to instance` when I perform the drag. `LblDrag` is a UILabel from IB, its an outlet. If I use an Action as the constructor parameter for the recogniser, it works fine, but I'd like to be able to use the selector approach.

Here is what I have:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var selector = new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("DragMe");
        var recognizer = new UIPanGestureRecognizer(LblDrag,selector);
        View.AddGestureRecognizer(recognizer);
    }

    [Export("DragMe")]
    protected void DragMe ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Drag");
    }
```

I have tried to change the View where the recognizer is being added to, neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's natural - you're adding the wrong target. `UILabel` doesn't respond to the `DragMe` selector (why do you assume it does?). You have to add the object as the target of the gesture recognizer that actually implements the callback method:

```
var recognizer = new UIPanGestureRecognizer(this, selector);
```

Comment: @Jeff No problem. It was just a logical guess (I don't know C#, but I'm glad this helped.)

Comment: I couldnt find any documentation about it, be it c# or objc, so Im glad you helped. :)